# difference between two methods use of the && operator

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, loops, testing, operators

Can someone please explain what the difference is between the following two methods?

I think perhaps I am misunderstanding the use of the && operator since the only syntactic difference is the arguments on each side of the operator. I would assume that it should not matter which one is on which side? Am I overlooking something?

Here are the two methods:

```
def nearest_larger(arr, i)
k = 1 

  loop do
    left = i - k
    right = i + k
      if (arr[i] < arr[left]) && (left >= 0)
        j = left
        return j
      elsif (arr[i] < arr[right]) && (right < arr.length)
        j = right
        return j
      elsif (right >= arr.length) && (left < 0)
        return nil
      end

  k += 1
  end

end


def nearest_larger(arr, i)
k = 1 

  loop do
    left = i - k
    right = i + k
      if (left >= 0) && (arr[i] < arr[left])
        j = left
        return j
      elsif (right < arr.length) && (arr[i] < arr[right])
        j = right
        return j
      elsif (right >= arr.length) && (left < 0)
        return nil
      end

  k += 1
  end

end
```

The bottom one passes the test while the top one gives me this error:

```
Failure/Error: nearest_larger( [2, 6, 4, 8], 3).should == nil
ArgumentError:
  comparison of Fixnum with nil failed
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The right hand side of the && operator only gets evaluated if the left hand side is true, because otherwise it would be a waste of time since you already know the whole statement is false if the left hand side is false.

In the bottom one, the code that is causing an error `(arr[i] < arr[right])` never gets evaluated to cause an error because `(right < arr.length)` is false.